# Select all data from all tables in a database and print into one table

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have 50 tables in my database. I would like to be able to select all the data from all the tables in my database and display it in one big html table. How would I go about doing it.

Instead of using -
     `($con,"SELECT * FROM table1 ORDER BY date DESC"); x50`

I would like to be able to do something like this - 
     `($con,"SELECT * FROM table1, table2, table3..... ORDER BY date DESC");` then

```
echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['date'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['time'] . "</td>";
```

THANKS eRIZ for the help!

Comment: Are the tables related to each other?

Comment: ...and have the tables the same structure?

Comment: The tables all contain the same data type and in the same format. So yes they all have the same structure

Comment: Why don't use **UNION**?

Comment: YES! Thats it many thanks eRIZ, You are the man

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the query like you shown won't lead to the desired result:

```
SELECT * FROM table1, table2, table3...
```

Will return a [Cartesian product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29) of all the columns in all the tables. If you want just a sequence of rows from all the tables, you need is a UNION:

```
(SELECT * FROM table1)
UNION
(SELECT * FROM table2)
UNION
(SELECT * FROM table3)
...
ORDER BY date DESC;
```